# "Ask {company} a question" modal <textarea> width should be locked

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, user-interface

I was just recently writing a question to a company using this feature.

[image: ask {company} a question feature]

I was adjusting the `textarea` to be vertically larger and accidentally extended it horizontally as well. Since the modal has a set width, it created a scroll.

[image: evil modal scrollbar!]

This obviously isn't incredibly important, but I thought I'd bring it to someone's attention.

Can the modal's textarea `resize` be locked to vertical only ie `resize:vertical;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going out in the next production build. Thanks for the report :)

Comment: the same thing happens on Area 51, if you're in a bug-fixing mood... :) http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/18746/the-comments-box-can-be-resized-in-both-directions